# How can I copy data from multiple sheets into a consolidated sheet in a single workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file with one main tab and **variable **number of secondary tabs.
I need to copy data from the secondary sheets into the primary sheet.
Each row in the secondary sheet has a unique ID, which is also present in the primary sheet.
I need to take 3 columns of data from each of the secondary sheet and copy it into the main sheet.
The 3 columns have the same name across sheets, but their order of appearance in each sheet can be jumbled up.

I tried using Vlookup across sheets but since the column names were same, I was not able to get results from other secondary sheets. Also since the number of secondary sheets is variable, I'm not sure how I can handle that using just Vlookup.

[This image has the main sheet with the 3 columns highlighted that I want to populate] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPoMn.png)
[This is one of the secondary sheets in the same workbook, I have highlighted the tabs where I need to extract the data from] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRjgb.png)

I would appreciate any pointers that could lead me in the right direction.
Let me know if any further clarification is needed.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$F$21,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$F$11,2,FALSE))
```

I tried this but this can only work for constant number of sheets and would be required to be hardcoded.

I also tried using VLOOKUP in combination with MATCH function to find the column in each sheet.
But since the column names are same in each sheet, I would only receive the first or the last result correct (Depending on how I looked for the value)

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SHEET1:SHEET4!$A$2:$F$21,MATCH("Column A",'SHeet1:Sheet4'!$A$1:$F$!',0),False)
```

Comment: Where will be placed the second secondary tab values in the primary sheet?

Comment: There are 3 empty columns in the primary sheet, they have the same column name as their counterparts in the secondary sheets from where we'll be taking the data.

Comment: Yes, thats clear,for one secondary sheet, but if both secondary sheets have the same ID where will be the second one's data placed. Inserting cells with worksheet functions not possible, so if you want to insert data with same ID from different sheets i suggest use macro which gives a wide variety of possibilities to manipulate data on your sheets.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, os the secondary sheets have different names but they share same column names and out of them we need to copy data from 3 of those and bring it into the main sheet. As for the IDs, each entry in the secondary sheets as a unique ID, they do not overlap. The screenshots I've added in the post give an example of how the structure looks like

Comment: Just had an idea. I'm thinking of looping through each secondary sheet and using vlookup between the main sheet and secondary sheet, I could get the values from the 3 coulumns using MATCH("Column A"...), MATCH("Column B"...), MATCH("Column C"...)

Comment: Managed to solve it but appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
    Sub AbraKadabra()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mainColA As Range
    Dim mainColB As Range
    Dim mainColC As Range
    Dim dataLastRow As Long
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim idColumn As Range
    Dim resultColumnA As Range
    Dim resultColumnB As Range
    Dim resultColumnC As Range
    Dim colNum1 As Integer
    Dim colNum2 As Integer
    Dim colNum3 As Integer
    Dim testVar As Variant
    
    ' Set the workbook and main sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set mainSheet = wb.Worksheets("mainSheet") ' Use main sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row in the main sheet
    lastRow = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    colNum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column A", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    colNum2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column B", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    colNum3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Column C", mainSheet.Rows(1), 0)
    
    Set mainColA = mainSheet.Columns(colNum1)
    Set mainColB = mainSheet.Columns(colNum2)
    Set mainColC = mainSheet.Columns(colNum3)

    ' Set the ranges for the main sheet columns
    ' Set mainColA = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' Set mainColB = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column B", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' Set mainColC = mainSheet.Rows(1).Find("Column C", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If mainColA Is Nothing Or mainColB Is Nothing Or mainColC Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "One or more column headers not found in the main sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

      ' Loop through each row in the main sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming the data starts from row 2, change as needed
        ' Get the ID for each row in the main sheet
        Dim id As Variant
        id = mainSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming the ID is in column A, change as needed
        
        ' Loop through each data sheet
        For Each dataSheet In wb.Sheets
            If dataSheet.Name <> mainSheet.Name Then ' Skip the main sheet itself
                ' Find the last row in the data sheet
                dataLastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                ' Set the range for the data sheet columns
                Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("A1:Z" & dataLastRow) ' Adjust the range as needed
                
                ' Set the range for the ID column and the result columns in the data sheet
                Set idColumn = dataRange.Columns(1) ' Assuming the ID column is in column A
                Set resultColumnA = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column A", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Set resultColumnB = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column B", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                Set resultColumnC = dataRange.Rows(1).Find("Column C", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                
                ' Set the lookup range for VLOOKUP
                ' Set lookupRange = dataRange.Columns(1) ' Assuming the lookup range is the ID column

                ' Use VLOOKUP to find the corresponding values in the data sheet
                Dim resultA As Variant
                Dim resultB As Variant
                Dim resultC As Variant
                resultA = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnA.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
                resultB = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnB.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)
                resultC = Application.VLookup(id, dataRange, resultColumnC.Column - dataRange.Columns(1).Column + 1, False)

                
                If Not IsError(resultA) Then
                    ' Populate particular columns in the main sheet with data from the data sheet
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColA.Column).Value = resultA
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColB.Column).Value = resultB
                    mainSheet.Cells(i, mainColC.Column).Value = resultC
                   
                    Exit For ' Exit the loop if a match is found in the current data sheet
                End If
            End If
        Next dataSheet
    Next i
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set mainSheet = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

So the code excludes the mainSheet and goes through every other sheet in the workbook.
The macro performs a vlookup on each sheet of the sheets individually to collect data from the required 3 columns and consolidates it into the main sheet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me the quickest solution would be to write a Power Query e.g.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    // List here any tables you do not want to include in the Consolidate results
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each 
        [Name] <> "Consolidated" and 
        [Name] <> "AnyOtherSheetsYouWantToExclude"),
    // Select the column names you require
    #"Expanded the tables" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", 
        {"ColHeading1 ", "ColHeading4", "ColHeading8"}, 
        {"ColHeading1 ", "ColHeading4", "ColHeading8"}),
    // Remove the sheet name if you like
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded the tables",{"Name"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

It will expect all of the data you are trying to consolidate to be in a table - the following VBA will step through your secondary tabs converting the data on them to tables with the same name as the sheet (caveat - this will only work for contiguous data)

```
Option Explicit
Sub SetupDataSheetsAsTables()

    'First set up a list of the sheets we are *not* interested in
    'This allows us to have a variable number of sheets that we are interested in
    Dim col As New Collection
    col.Add "", "Sheet1"
    col.Add "", "Consolidated"
    col.Add "", "AnotherSheet"

    'For each sheet in this workbook that is not in the list above, select the data from A1
    'across the contiguous region and convert it to a table with the same name as the sheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ExistsInCollection(col, ws.Name) Then
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = ws.Name
        End If
    Next

End Sub
Public Function ExistsInCollection(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err_hand
    ExistsInCollection = True
    IsObject col.Item(key)
    Exit Function
err_hand:
    ExistsInCollection = False
End Function
```

You will need to change the column headers and sheet names to match your own scenario